# Rails templates and AngularJS databind combine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, erb

How can I use rails templating <%= %> with angularjs data binding {{}}. Example <%= {{ dataConfess.confess }} %> . I know this is an error. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string:

```
<%= "{{ dataConfess.confess }}" %>
```

After render it will look like:

```
{{ dataConfess.confess }}
```